# How to ignore the certificate is untrusted in pjsip for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sip, pjsip, lync-server-2010

- Currentlly, I have built successfully the pjsip library for the iPhone SDK version 5.1. And I have built successfully for OpenSSL Suport.
- I use this library in order to login to Server Lync by command as below:

b1: +a

b2: hn.fisil@nextuc.net

b3: sip.nextuc.net;transport=tls

b4: sip.nextuc.net

b5: hn.fisil

b6: pass

I always get an error as below:

2012-07-18 13:46:42.403 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.402    pjsua_app.c  **TLS cert verification result of [sip.nextuc.net:5061] : The certificate is untrusted**\
2012-07-18 13:46:42.405 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.405    pjsua_app.c  **PJSUA is configured to ignore TLS cert verification errors**

How to ignore error/warning that certificate is untrusted in pjsip

Please help me.

==============================================================================
**The following is whole log:**

```
2012-07-18 13:46:11.262 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.262    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net

2012-07-18 13:46:11.265 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.265    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net added with id 3

2012-07-18 13:46:11.268 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.268    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 3: setting registration..

2012-07-18 13:46:11.271 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.271    pjsua_acc.c  ..Contact for acc 3 updated for SIP outbound: <sip:hn.fisil@10.0.0.29:5061;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00005f38fd37>"

2012-07-18 13:46:11.420 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.420  tlsc0x1346214  ...TLS client transport created

2012-07-18 13:46:11.424 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.424  tlsc0x1346214  ...TLS transport 10.0.0.29:49659 is connecting to sip.nextuc.net:5061...

2012-07-18 13:46:11.427 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.426   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 669 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=1274 (tdta0xb8aa00) to tls 108.166.11.10:5061:
REGISTER sip:sip.nextuc.net;transport=tls SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.0.29:49659;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPju0MvTx5itoPOYx4mTYTotLcWStES2gqc
Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net>;tag=xuLN729d-2nPKZHA.mqqSbh1s0MKCd16

To: <sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net>

Call-ID: KJUJOcZtCYrmMTP5TD721o--wFQScx83

CSeq: 1274 REGISTER

User-Agent: PJSUA v2.0-rc-svn iPhone OS-5.1/arm/iOS-SDK-5.1

Supported: outbound, path

Contact: <sip:hn.fisil@10.0.0.29:5061;transport=TLS;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="

<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00005f38fd37>"

Expires: 300

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0

--end msg--

2012-07-18 13:46:11.429 ipjsua[434:5103] 13:46:11.429    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 3: Registration sent

2012-07-18 13:46:11.431 ipjsua[434:5103] >>> 
pardtx560pardeftab560qlqnaturalpardirnatural

f1b0 cf0 [Switching to process 10243 thread 0x2803]
pardtx560pardeftab560qlqnaturalpardirnatural

f0b cf0 2012-07-18 13:46:42.395 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.394    pjsua_app.c !SIP tls transport is connected to [sip.nextuc.net:5061]

2012-07-18 13:46:42.397 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.397    pjsua_app.c  TLS cipher used: 0x000004/RC4-MD5

2012-07-18 13:46:42.398 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.398    pjsua_app.c  TLS cert info of [sip.nextuc.net:5061]:

  Version    : v3

  Serial     : 09 37 73 71 79 66 C3 49 C0 C0 9F CB E8 73 D8 D5

  Subject    : sip.nextuc.net
               /C=US/ST=Utah/L=South Jordan/O=NextUC/CN=sip.nextuc.net

Issuer     : DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
               /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3

Valid from : Tue 2011-01-18 00:00:00.000 GMT

Valid to   : Mon 2013-01-21 12:00:00.000 GMT

subjectAltName extension

DNS : sip.nextuc.net

         DNS : sip.nextuc.com

         DNS : sip.lyncucs.com

         DNS : sip.lyncweb.com

         DNS : sip.lyncdude.com

         DNS : sip.criticalpathtraining.com

         DNS : sip.lynxinteractive.com

         DNS : sip.cyberuc.com

         DNS : sip.vardynamics.com

         DNS : sip.calstrawberry.net

         DNS : sip.na.pgi.com

         DNS : sip.cowperthwaiteco.com

         DNS : sip.securitymicro.com

         DNS : sip.jmaventuresllc.com

         DNS : sip.asylument.com

         DNS : sip.getsimplyclean.com

         DNS : sip.totalofficeapplications.com

         DNS : sip.nucadence.com

         DNS : sip.caroluscapitaladvisors.com

         DNS : sip.360sync.us

         DNS : sip.invoicewareint.com

         DNS : sip.misystems.com

         DNS : sip.citrius.com

         DNS : sip.jhanrahan.com

         DNS : sip.calmico.com

         DNS : sip.360sync.ca

         DNS : sip.dynamiktek.com

         DNS : sip.plannedgivingmarketing.com

         DNS : sip.honeycutt.com

         DNS : sip.mbagz.com

         DNS : sip.pr1it.com

         DNS : sip.office365team.com

         DNS : sip.plannedgiving.com

         DNS : sip.green-itconsulting.com

         DNS : sip.lync-demo.com

         DNS : sip.innerworkings.com

         DNS : sip.lyncweb.net

         DNS : sip.voxogo.com

         DNS : sip.artcgroupinc.com

         DNS : sip.buddy.com

         DNS : sip.yanceyworks.com

         DNS : sip.intuplex.com

         DNS : sip.ziptonlabs.com

         DNS : sip.christnertech.com

         DNS : sip.grahamcg.com

         DNS : sip.sumoet.com

2012-07-18 13:46:42.403 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.402    pjsua_app.c  TLS cert verification result of [sip.nextuc.net:5061] : The certificate is untrusted

2012-07-18 13:46:42.405 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.405    pjsua_app.c  PJSUA is configured to ignore TLS cert verification errors

2012-07-18 13:46:42.407 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.407  tlsc0x1346214  TLS transport 10.0.0.29:49659 is connected to sip.nextuc.net:5061

2012-07-18 13:46:42.679 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.679   pjsua_core.c  .RX 460 bytes Response msg 504/REGISTER/cseq=1274 (rdata0x13463c4) from tls 108.166.11.10:5061:
SIP/2.0 504 Server time-out
ms-user-logon-data: RemoteUser
From: <sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net>;tag=xuLN729d-2nPKZHA.mqqSbh1s0MKCd16
To: <sip:hn.fisil@nextuc.net>;tag=EF0526A2E37D90799792ED71161FA886
Call-ID: KJUJOcZtCYrmMTP5TD721o--wFQScx83
CSeq: 1274 REGISTER
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 10.0.0.29:49659;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPju0MvTx5itoPOYx4mTYTotLcWStES2gqc;received=115.78.227.37;ms-received-port=57093;ms-received-cid=21E5D00
Server: RTC/4.0
Content-Length: 0


--end msg--

2012-07-18 13:46:42.683 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.682    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=504 (Server time-out)

2012-07-18 13:46:42.685 ipjsua[434:5f03] 13:46:42.685    pjsua_acc.c  ....Scheduling re-registration retry for acc 3 in 4 seconds
```

Comment: Have you get solution?